# How to change API level 8 to 3 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse for android where my API level is 8, i tried project->properties->android-> but here it it showing me only one checkbox for API level 8. please guide me what to do??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i tried project->properties->android-> but here it it showing me only one checkbox for API level 8. please guide me what to do??

Off course it shows only one checkbox for API level 8, because may be you have downloaded only the `SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8` And API level 3 means you want to run your application on Android 1.5. So you also have to download `SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3`

To download this open the `Android SDK and AVD Manager` and click on `Available Packages`. Here you can find `SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3` inside the `Android Repository` and after downloading this you have to create a new `Android Virtual Device` by selecting Target as `Android 1.5 API Level 3`. After that you will be able to change API Level 8 to 3

Answer (score 4):

First: Install the desidered apis in your AVD-Manager.

Second: You have also to change the line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml

best regards

Answer (score -1):

Start your SDK and AVD manager, choose "Installed Packages" and delete the unnessecary APIs.